# Обращение по индексу в unordered_map

Tags: c++, stl, c++11

не могу понять в чем проблемма, так все хорошо:

```
    unordered_map <int, int> I;
    I.emplace(2, 20);
    cout << I[2] << endl;
```

но если храню в контейнере экземпляры некого класса, то обращение [] вызывает ошибку компиляции
например:

```
    class A {
        public:
            int b,
                c;
        A (int b_, int c_): b(b_), c(c_) {};
    };

    int main()
    {
        unordered_map <int, A> X;
            X.emplace(1, A(1, 1));
            X.emplace(2, A(2, 1));

        cout << X[1].b << endl; // ошибка
        A tmp(10,10);
        X[5] = tmp; // тоже ошибка

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: А какая ошибка? Там обычно написана причина.

Comment: попробуйте заменить class на struct возможно что-то с конструкторами копирования.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Проблема в том, что Ваш класс не имеет конструктора по-умолчанию. Достаточно добавить его, и программа скомпилируется:

```
A (int b_, int c_): b(b_), c(c_) {};
A(): A(0, 0) {} // <---
```

Пункт стандарта #23.5.4.3:

> ```
> mapped_type& operator[](const key_type& k);
> mapped_type& operator[](key_type&& k);
> ```
>
> Requires: `mapped_type` shall be `DefaultConstructible`.

Comment: это действительно так